# How can I finish the unfinished transaction, so then I can make all the updates?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos-6

I try to use yum update and everytime it says me to run yum-complete-transaction first to finish the unfinished transactions remaining.

When I try, it loops like forever, and sometimes it ends by saying me that these 2 packages are uninstalled: 
sendmail.x86_64 0:8.14.4-8.el6
sendmail-cf.noarch 0:8.14.4-8.el6

Then I try to install them using yum install, and I'm back in the infinite loop ending with the same message that I should first consider running yum-complete-transaction.

**EDIT**
*And I forgot to say: when I use yum-complete-transaction, it just never ends until it aborts, I set timeout at 300.*

Is there a way out of this maze?

The OS is CentOS 6.4, I am using WinSCP on Windows 8.

Comment: Make sure there are no other instances of yum running in the background. Then try using the `--cleanup-only` option, like so:`yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only -v`

Comment: Thanks, it did the job. unfortunalety I can't upvote you, I don't have privilege yet.

Comment: Similar infinite loop with yum-complete-transaction happened to me on Centos 7.  This helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there are no other instances of yum running in the background. Then try using the `--cleanup-only` option, like so: `yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only -v`